# liferay "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH" for images(even for small images from DLFileEntry objects)

Tags: java, liferay-6

I'm using liferay - liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5 version, and my images are saved in DLFileEntry objects. Now I'm able get the download link urls and successfully display images in Firefox browser. But in chrome I'm facing issue with images.
While loading the images the images are shown up, but Once the loading is completed the images are dis-appeared. Infact in console its giving the below warning,

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

So as per [this](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-44255) liferay jira issue, it seems to be resolved in 6.x prior version itself. But still I'm facing this issue.

Anybody have any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue :) While saving the DLFileEntry in database for this image, It asked the size of the File too. There I have given wrong parameter value, Means I've given huge memory space for this file entry. So while populating in chrome, chrome browser is cross-checking for its size with the size which we have provided, eventually those two are not matching. So Its throwing the above error. So gave actual size of the file now, which is working fine..